# Reversing x domain on dc.js series chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Looking at [this sample `dc.js` series chart](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html):

[image]

How do I reverse the *x*-axis so it descends from 20 to 0, with the plotted series reversing accordingly?

I was able to do this in a pure `d3.js` chart by reversing the order of `x.domain`. When I try to do this for the chart above by changing:

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]))
```

to

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([20,0]))
```

The numbers on the *x*-axis reverse, but the lines disappear.

Comment: I'd try adding a range component.  That is, change `.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]))` to `.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]).range([20,0]))`

Comment: I'd test it out for you but due to local CSVs I don't think I can.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look...just tried that and it didn't work. Here's a link to the csv file if that helps. https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/morley.csv

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/jsT42/.  The "line-chart-reverse" shows the axis reversed but the data points are missing.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug, specifically this one:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/525